# Partial View different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use a partial view that uses a different model than the one used in the main view. The partial view has
to show a list with the products recently added. But I am stuck on how and where to implement the logic for retrieving the data I need from the database.

```
Home/Index.cshtml:

@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_LatestProducts.cshtml", new List<Website.Models.LatestProductsList>())


Shared/_LatestProducts.cshtml:

@model List<Website.Models.LatestProductsList>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <a href="#" title="img">
    <img src="~/Content/images/latest-product-img.jpg" alt="" /><p>@item.ProductName</p>
    </a>
}
```

And I have the following code that I am trying to use in order to get some products for tests and show them in the partial view:

```
public PartialViewResult _LatestProducts()
{
    List<LatestProductsList> latestProd = (from p in db.Products
                                           where p.ID < 5
                                           select new LatestProductsList { ProductName = p.Title }).ToList();

    return PartialView(latestProd);
}
```

I thought that I might use it in the HomeController, but that obviously doesn't work and I am not sure if partial views should have their own controller, if I can
just call it from another class. I am still wrapping my head around ASP MVC, so any help will be appreciate it.

Comment: you can specify which view you want to use in the controller action. the loading from database logic happens in the DAL, which will be called from your services layer, which I called from your controller.

Comment: What is the view-model of `Index`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call the action that renders the partial view in Index.cshtml.

```
@Html.Action("_LatestProducts", "Product")
```

Second parameter is the name of the controller that has the _LatestProducts method.

---

*Just a reminder: Names with `_` prefix is for partial views only, not action methods. You should rename it to `LatestProducts`.*